# Not able to locate input element using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am new to Selenium. In a specific scenario I am not able to catch an input element. below is the code:

```
<ul class = "form1">
    <li class="firstName">
        <input placeholdervalue="First name" tabindex="1" placeholder="First name" class="text" placeholdevalue="First name" data-input-rule="name" data-value-rule="required" maxlength="20" type="text">
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to locate input element. I tried locating it using locator `By.ClassName`, `By.CssSelector("input[class='text placeholder']")` and also tried:

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.CssSelector("input[className='text' and placeholdevalue='First name'"))).SendKeys("Vipul");
```

but input element is not getting selected.
Please let me know the right way to select input element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a *`dot` notation* to match the classes of `ul`, `li` and `input` elements:

```
By.CssSelector("ul.form1 li.firstName input.text")
```

If the element still cannot be found, then there could two most commonly met reasons:

- it is inside an iframe and you need to *switch to it*
- you need to *wait for the element* to appear

I'll expand these items in case you would still have problems finding the element.

Comment: would like to point out, @Amit, that this notation is using `By.CssSelector`   `.`'s in CSS is equivalent to `[class~='...']`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the reply.

It worked with this,

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.CssSelector("ul.form1 li.firstName input.text"))).SendKeys("Vipul");
```

Is this the right way of using wait?

Also, can anybody point out to resources which explain working with frames using selenium webdriver?

-Amit